# Java: блок внутри функции, его польза

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.
Собственно, вопрос в том, какой практический смысл конструкции, когда выделяется блок внутри метода. Что-то типа этого:

```
void method() {
    { System.out.println("что-то делаем") }
    //и остальной код
}
```

Comment: @Антон Мухин  Если в организации оценивают труд программиста по числу набранных знаков, то имеет прямой практический смысл.

Comment: Там именно `System.out` или что-то еще?

Comment: @defaultlocale Что угодно. System.out я вписал в качестве како-го нибудь примера.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть несколько сценариев, в которых могут быть использованы блоки.

1. Ограничение области видимости переменных.

У переменных, определенных в блоке, областью видимости является блок. В результате в разных блоках можно определять переменные с одинаковыми названиями:

```
{
String test = "test";
//используем test в первом блоке
}
{
String test = "test2"; 
//используем test во втором блоке
}
```

2. Именованные метки.

На блок можно поставить метку, после чего из блока можно будет выходить с помощью `break`.

```
A: {
    //где-то в глубине выходим из блока
    if(isFinishedA()) {
        break A;
    }
    //продолжается блок
}
//продолжается метод
```

3. Отладка. На строку внутри блока можно поставить точку останова.

Стоит заметить, что во всех перечисленных случаях вместо блока можно использовать другие подходы (разделение на методы, тесты, изменение логики). Соответственно, необходимость локальных блоков спорна.

Похожий вопрос на английском: [Is there a use of free floating block inside a method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514583/is-there-a-use-of-free-floating-block-inside-a-method-in-java)